# how to get the last login date and created date from azure active directory through C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-b2c

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var signIns = await graphClient.**AuditLogs**.SignIns
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

I will not able to read the AuditLogs from graphclient.
Could you pleas help to get the lastlogin date and created date from the azure AD using C# code.

Getting this below error while reading the data :

> Error  CS1061  'GraphServiceClient' does not contain a definition for 'AuditLogs' and no accessible extension method 'AuditLogs' accepting a first argument of type 'GraphServiceClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have admin access to the tenant?

Comment: yes i have access

Comment: https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-azure-ad-last-login-date-and-sign-in-activity/

Comment: I have to use the C# code only.

Comment: Could you please let us know that you have added the SDK to your project and created an `authProvider` instance.  May it helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-list-all-sign-ins

Comment: Also try to install Nuget package  Microsoft.Graph.Beta  .

Answer (score 1):

Based on MS DOC:

> **Microsoft Graph SDKs** use the ***v1.0*** version of
> the API by default, and do not support all the types, properties, and
> APIs available in the beta version. For details about accessing the
> beta API with the SDK, see [Use the Microsoft Graph SDKs with the beta
> API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta).

The below code works for Microsoft Graph SDKs with the beta API:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Select("displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity")
    .GetAsync();
```

The below code is used to list the sign-in time of users with a specific display name.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("startswith(displayName,'Eric')")
    .Select("displayName,signInActivity")
    .GetAsync();
```

For more detailed information, please visit [listing the users data through C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#example-3-get-users-including-their-last-sign-in-time).

Comment: Also based on MS doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/versioning-and-support) : "Expect breaking changes and deprecation of APIs in the beta version from time to time. Do not take a production dependency on beta APIs."